# object-fit unexpected result in firefox

Tags: html, css, materialize

**Due to reputation restrictions, I'm not able to post images. But [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TLxk.jpg) is the link to the image I want to show.**

[image]

I am using the "cards" component of the [Materialize.css](http://materializecss.com/). I have this card with an image on top and I have applied the `object-fit` css3 property to that image. The property behaves well on Google Chrome, however, on Firefox, which should support `object-fit` property, the image is not appearing as I expected it to be. I have tried searching for possible css prefixes, workarounds like re-wrapping them in a `div` but none of these work. Here is my code:

CSS:

```
.card-officer .card-image img {
    object-fit: cover; /* Do not scale the image */
    object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
    height: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="card card-officer hoverable">
    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
        <div>
            <img class="activator" src="profile.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
        <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Patrick Joshua Sarmiento</span>
        <h6>Public Information Officer</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I achieve the effect of the `object-fit` on Firefox and other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering with the css, here is what I've got:

The `will-change: opacity, transform` property of the `waves-effect` class in the Materialize.css plugin causes the `object-fit` to prevent from behaving properly. I've did this by resetting the value of the `will-change: auto` for the affected `div`'s.